# Trying to create a proc but getting error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a procedure which will return concatenated  value but getting error.

I have created a procedure name "GetMultiVal" and inside that created a cursor 'stage_val'for fetching value .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetMultiVal
(v_var_value out varchar2,v_hr_stk_out out Sys_Refcursor)
is
var_value varchar2(200);
x varchar2   (200);
cursor age_val is
 SELECT AGE_CD,
 decode(AGE_CD,'07','CLNE(RW','05','CS ','4A',NULL,AGE_DESC) AGE_DESC ,
 AGE_SEQ
 FROM DBPROD.PROD_AGE_MST
 WHERE AGE_SEQ < 15
 AND AGE_CD NOT IN ('6A','05')
 ORDER BY 3;
BEGIN
OPEN v_hr_stk_out For
    FOR i IN age_val LOOP
      SELECT To_Char(Round(NVL(SUM(NVL(ROD_WT, 0)), 0), 0))
      INTO X
      FROM DBPROD.Prod_age_fgs_cur
    WHERE WF_DATE BETWEEN sysdate AND  sysdate+1
       AND WF_AGE_CD=i.AGE_CD;
    var_value :=var_value || X||'~';
       END LOOP;
    select var_value as v_var_value from dual;
end;
end;
```

**Expected:** should get concatenated value in v_var_value variable.

**Actual**: getting error Compilation errors for PROCEDURE DBPROD.GETMULTIVAL

> Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:

Answer (score 2):

you don't Need to open a Cursor if you use it in a for Loop.

try this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getmultival(v_var_value  out varchar2
                                       ,v_hr_stk_out out Sys_Refcursor) is
  var_value varchar2(200);
  x         varchar2(200);
  cursor age_val is
    SELECT age_cd
          ,decode(age_cd, '07', 'CLNE(RW', '05', 'CS ', '4A', NULL, age_desc) age_desc
          ,age_seq
      FROM dbprod.prod_age_mst
     WHERE age_seq < 15
       AND age_cd NOT IN ('6A', '05')
     ORDER BY 3;
BEGIN

  open v_hr_stk_out  for
   SELECT age_cd
          ,decode(age_cd, '07', 'CLNE(RW', '05', 'CS ', '4A', NULL, age_desc) age_desc
          ,age_seq
      FROM dbprod.prod_age_mst
     WHERE age_seq < 15
       AND age_cd NOT IN ('6A', '05')
     ORDER BY 3;



  FOR i IN age_val LOOP
    SELECT to_char(round(nvl(SUM(nvl(rod_wt, 0)), 0), 0))
      INTO x
      FROM dbprod.prod_age_fgs_cur
     WHERE wf_date BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate + 1
       AND wf_age_cd = i.age_cd;
    var_value := var_value || x || '~';
  END LOOP; 

  v_var_value := var_value ;

end;
```

Comment: @hotflix OPEN v_hr_stk_out For  line has been removed but it is required how is it possible

Comment: @Mohan i have changed the last line in a proc, that was also not correct

Comment: ok i see, but it is not clear why you have the cursor as the output parameter and at the same time access it in the procedure?

Comment: @hotflix actually there is multiple values coming from different function so i was planning to get value of each other function in different out ref cursor and in the given example i was using only one similarly i was trying for many so that i can read from out sys_Refcursor

Comment: @Mohan I have adapted my answer. Your concept is not quite clean in my opinion.

Comment: @hotflix if there are values coming from different tables and all i want to call in same proc and under different out ref cursor how could i achieve any idea ,then please share

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to re-build your procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETMULTIVAL (
    V_VAR_VALUE    OUT            VARCHAR2,
    V_HR_STK_OUT   OUT            SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS

    VAR_VALUE   VARCHAR2(200);
    X           VARCHAR2(200);
--    CURSOR AGE_VAL IS
--    SELECT
--        AGE_CD,
--        DECODE(AGE_CD, '07', 'CLNE(RW', '05', 'CS ', '4A', NULL, AGE_DESC) AGE_DESC,
--        AGE_SEQ
--    FROM
--        DBPROD.PROD_AGE_MST
--    WHERE
--        AGE_SEQ < 15
--        AND AGE_CD NOT IN (
--            '6A',
--            '05'
--        )
--    ORDER BY
--        3;

BEGIN
    OPEN V_HR_STK_OUT FOR 
    SELECT
        AGE_CD,
        DECODE(AGE_CD, '07', 'CLNE(RW', '05', 'CS ', '4A', NULL, AGE_DESC) AGE_DESC,
        AGE_SEQ
    FROM
        DBPROD.PROD_AGE_MST
    WHERE
        AGE_SEQ < 15
        AND AGE_CD NOT IN (
            '6A',
            '05'
        )
    ORDER BY
        3;


--    FOR i IN age_val LOOP
--        SELECT to_char(round(nvl(SUM(nvl(rod_wt, 0)), 0), 0))
--          INTO x
--          FROM dbprod.prod_age_fgs_cur
--         WHERE wf_date BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate + 1
--           AND wf_age_cd = i.age_cd;
--        var_value := var_value || x || '~';
--      END LOOP; 

    SELECT
        LISTAGG(ROUND(NVL(SUM(NVL(ROD_WT, 0)), 0), 0), '~') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                M.AGE_SEQ
        )
    INTO VAR_VALUE
    FROM
        DBPROD.PROD_AGE_MST M
        JOIN DBPROD.PROD_AGE_FGS_CUR A ON ( A.WF_AGE_CD = M.AGE_CD )
    WHERE
        A.WF_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE AND SYSDATE + 1
        AND M.AGE_SEQ < 15
        AND M.AGE_CD NOT IN (
            '6A',
            '05'
        );

    V_VAR_VALUE := VAR_VALUE;
END;
```

No need to define explicit cursor to find the value for `V_VAR_VALUE`, It can be achieved using a single join.

Test it in your DB as I don't have any sample data and DDL.

Hope, This will give direction toward a solution.

Cheers!!